# Combining places search and kml layers with toggle on google maps api

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, kml

I am attempting to create a map with multiple kml layers that can be toggled with the google places search, but have been unsuccessful.  The purpose of this is to have the ability to search an address or intersection and determine the correct response apparatus for fire or medical calls for a dispatch center, with the search being biased toward the correct county.  I have the base map with just one layer working [here](http://siouxfallsmetrocommunications.github.io/), but I've been unable to correctly integrate the kml layer toggle with the google places search.  I had received some good input from [geocodezip](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1210329/geocodezip) on using the geocode function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32893142/toggle-multiple-kml-layers-and-include-search-box-in-google-maps), but I wasn't able to bias it towards the correct location or include the predictive search completion.  I also like the way that my original map will zoom and center on the searched address and would like to maintain that functionality.  Admittedly, I am very much lacking in ability with this, and everything I have done has been to simply copy and modify working examples that others have posted, but I have not found any working examples that include both the google places search and kml layers with toggle.  This is what I have so far.  Any help in getting this to work would be very much appreciated.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
.controls {
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 32px;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
#pac-input {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-left: 12px;
  padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 300px;
}
#pac-input:focus {
  border-color: #4d90fe;
}
.pac-container {
  font-family: Roboto;
}
#type-selector {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4d90fe;
  padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;
}
#type-selector label {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 300;
}
    </style>
    <title>Advanced Backup Map</title>
    <style>
      #target {
        width: 345px;
      }
    </style>
    
    <script>
    
      var kml = {
    a: {
        name: "Fire Response Areas",
        url: "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B2gbIV1dXlvDVDhVLXc2N1Y5ZEE"
    },
    b: {
        name: "SD Counties",
        url: "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B2gbIV1dXlvDRndwdEpKTjRBeTA"
    },
    c: {
        name: "Counties in Surrounding States",
        url: "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B2gbIV1dXlvDRlhLTm93S2Y3eDQ"
    }
    // keep adding more if ye like 
  };
    
// This example adds a search box to a map, using the Google Place Autocomplete
// feature. People can enter geographical searches. The search box will return a
// pick list containing a mix of places and predicted search terms.
function initAutocomplete() {
  // lets define some vars to make things easier later
  
  var options = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.64837, -96.73737),
    zoom: 10,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);
  createTogglers();
  
  // Append Class on Select
function highlight(box, listitem) {
    var selected = 'selected';
    var normal = 'normal';
    document.getElementById(listitem).className = (box.checked ? selected : normal);
};
function startup() {
    // for example, this toggles kml a on load and updates the menu selector
    var checkit = document.getElementById('a');
    checkit.checked = true;
    toggleKML(checkit, 'a');
    highlight(checkit, 'selector1');
};
  // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
  var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
  new google.maps.LatLng(43.38218, -97.29373),
  new google.maps.LatLng(43.92451, -96.34532));
  
  var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
  var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input, {
  bounds: defaultBounds
});
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
  // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
  map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
    searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
  });
  var markers = [];
  // [START region_getplaces]
  // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
  // more details for that place.
  searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();
    if (places.length == 0) {
      return;
    }
    // Clear out the old markers.
    markers.forEach(function(marker) {
      marker.setMap(null);
    });
    markers = [];
    // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    places.forEach(function(place) {
      var icon = {
        url: place.icon,
        size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
      };
      // Create a marker for each place.
      markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        icon: icon,
        title: place.name,
        position: place.geometry.location
      }));
      if (place.geometry.viewport) {
        // Only geocodes have viewport.
        bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
      } else {
        bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
      }
    });
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
       map.setZoom(16);
   map.setCenter(center);
   });
  // [END region_getplaces]
// the important function... kml[id].xxxxx refers back to the top 
function toggleKML(checked, id) {
    if (checked) {
        var layer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(kml[id].url, {
            preserveViewport: true,
            suppressInfoWindows: false
        });
        // store kml as obj
        kml[id].obj = layer;
        kml[id].obj.setMap(map);
    }
    else {
        kml[id].obj.setMap(null);
        delete kml[id].obj;
    }
};
// create the controls dynamically because it's easier, really
function createTogglers() {
    var html = "<form><ul>";
    for (var prop in kml) {
        html += "<li id=\"selector-" + prop + "\"><input type='checkbox' id='" + prop + "'" +
        " onclick='highlight(this,\"selector-" + prop + "\"); toggleKML(this.checked, this.id)' \/>" +
        kml[prop].name + "<\/li>";
    }
    document.getElementById("toggle_box").innerHTML = html;
};
}
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBhTQXonppCE2eVDQO5AHy11kMn-o27m_U&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
         async defer></script>
    
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="toggle_box" style="position: absolute; top: 10px; right: 10px; padding: 5px; background: #fff; z-index: 1; "></div>

  </body>
</html>
```